# Tensor Product of Fields is a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, tensor-products

I have two questions about a construction introduced in  Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (see page 122):

[image]

We fix an integral proper normal curve $X$ over a field $k$. We consider it's function field $K$ which is a finite extension of $k(t)$ and take an arbitrary field extension $L \vert k$.

The point of interest is the resulting tensor product $K \otimes L$. We know that $K \otimes L$ is finite dimensional $L(t)$-algebra.

Following two questions:

1. Assume $K \otimes L$ is a finite direct product of fields $L_i$. Why these fields are finitely generated (as $L$-modules)?
2. Assume non $k$ is algebraically closed. Why is $K \otimes L$ then a field?
  1.

Comment: If $L/k$ is separable then the primitive element gives $L = k[x]/(f)$ and $K \otimes_k L = K[x]/(f) = K[x]/(\prod_j f_j) = \prod_j K[x]/(f_j)$ since $f$ separable implies the $(f_j)$ are comaximal. If $k$ is algebraically closed and $L/k$ is a tower of purely transcendental and algebraic extensions then rename the transcendental elements so they are not in $\overline{K}$ thus the algebraic extensions keep the same degree with $k$ or $K$ as the basefield

Comment: I'm quite not sure if it is possible to reduce the problem 1. to the case when $L \vert k$ is separable. Or why do you implicitely assumed that?

Comment: If $K$ is a finite extension of $k(t)$ then $K = k(t)[Y_1,\ldots,Y_m]/I$, finitely generated as field, not as an algebra or module, and if $K \otimes_k L = L(t)[Y_1,\ldots,Y_m]/I= \prod_j L_j$ then each $L_j$ is a quotient of $L(t)[Y_1,\ldots,Y_m]/I$, finitely generated as a field over $L$.

Comment: @reuns: yes,  so the 1. question is solved.

Concerning the second one I'm a bit confused. Assume $k$ is algebraically closed. $K$ is finite extension of $k(t)$ and therefore has transcendence degree $1$ over $k$. On the other hand $L \vert k$ might be an arbitrary extension.

Comment: Then Grothendieck-Sharp tells as in 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82083/when-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-fields-a-field that $\dim_{\mathrm{Krull}}(K\otimes_k L) = \min(\operatorname{trdeg}_k(K),\operatorname{trdeg}_k(L))$. Then if we take as $L$ for example a transcendent extension $k(t)$ of $k$ we obtain $\dim_{\mathrm{Krull}}(K\otimes_k L)=1$ so the tensor product can't be a field. But this contradicts the statement 2. The author didn't explicitely siad that $L \vert k$ should be a finite extension

Comment: @reuns You can only use the primitive element theorem if $L$ is finite and separable, and the quoted text only assumes that $L$ is algebraic and separable. How are you reducing to the case where $L$ is finite?

Comment: @jgon: I think that in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82083/when-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-fields-a-field the OP presents a acceptable solution. See below Theorem Grothendieck-Sharp. I'm not sure if this is the "classical" way to verify it but the argument works. On the other hand another point that irritates me reading the excerpt is the formulation: "... the assumption on $K ⊗_k L$ is satisfied when $L|k $ is a separable algebraic extension, ***or*** when $k$ is algebraically closed ..."

Comment: I think that this suggests a highly wrong suspicion that $k$ if is algebraically closed one don't need the requirement that $L \vert k$ algebraically and separable for $K\otimes_k L$ a field.

Comment: @KarlPeter While your comment perhaps provides a solution, it doesn't address my question to reuns. Also when $k$ is algebraically closed you indeed do not need $L/k$ algebraic and separable. Indeed, that doesn't even make sense, since the only algebraic extension of an algebraically closed field is the field itself.

Comment: Also the answer to your question why are the $L_i$ finitely generated $L$ modules is that they are not. They are finite over $L(t)$, as is said explicitly in the text next to your first red arrow.

Comment: @jgon What would be your solution ? I'd say for $K/k(t)$ finite with normal closure $N/k(t)$ and $L/k$ infinite separable, for any finite subextension $\ell/k$ then $K \otimes_k \ell$ will be a product of $d(\ell) \le [(\overline{k} \cap N):k]$ fields so for $\ell$ large enough the maximum for $d(\ell)$ is attained and we can look at $K \otimes_k \ell=\prod_{j=1}^{d(\ell)}L_j$, $K \otimes_kL=K \otimes_k (\ell \otimes_\ell L)=(K \otimes_k \ell) \otimes_\ell L =(\prod_{j=1}^{d(\ell)} L_j) \otimes_\ell L= \prod_{j=1}^{d(\ell)} (L_j \otimes_\ell L)$ the latter being fields by a dimension argument.

Comment: @jgon: so I think that the author indeed means that $L_i$ are finitely generated ***as algebras*** or ***fields*** over $L$

Comment: @KarlPeter Yes, the author means that the $L_i$ are finitely generated as fields over $L$. Finitely generated algebras over a field are either finite field extensions or not fields.